# Regarding generator function send() javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was viewing generator functions in Mozilla Dev page.

There was an example code which is having **send()** function.

```
function* fibonacci() {
  var a = yield 1;
  yield a * 2;
}

var it = fibonacci();
console.log(it);          // "Generator {  }"
console.log(it.next());   // 1
console.log(it.send(10)); // 20
console.log(it.close());  // undefined
console.log(it.next());   // throws StopIteration (as the generator is now closed)
```

But, both chrome and Firefox (Latest version) are throwing error on send() function.

Any views on this? Is it not supported?

Comment: As i recall, only limited browsers support ES6, you better use transpilers like BabelJS

Comment: In ES6, there's only a `next` method that you pass values into. What page exactly are you looking at? Please link it so that we can fix it (don't forget MDN is a wiki!)

Comment: link please, i can't find the doc

Answer (score 2):

`.send` is part of the [Legacy generator objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator#Legacy_generator_objects) which are specific to the SpiderMonkey engine. [It will be removed in some future release](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/legacy-iterator-and-generator-support-will-be-removed/). They have already started removing/replacing the legacy generator objects with ES6 generators in parts of their code ([Bug 1215846](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215846), [Bug 1133277](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133277))

For the moment you can still use legacy generators in Firefox (current version as of this answer: 43.0.4). Just leave off the `*` when defining, and as long as the function body uses a `yield` statement the legacy generator will be used.

```
function fibonacci() {
  var a = yield 1;
  yield a * 2;
}

var it = fibonacci();
console.log(it);          
console.log(it.next());   
console.log(it.send(10)); 
console.log(it.close());  
console.log(it.next());
```

Answer (score -2):

Interesting that in ESNext might be function.sent()

```
var result;
function* generator() {
  result = function.sent;
}
var iter = generator();
iter.next('tromple');
return result === 'tromple';
```

https://github.com/allenwb/ESideas/blob/master/Generator%20metaproperty.md

Comment: Yes, but this has little to do with this question.